# Публикация проекта dotnet react через Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net

Пытаюсь опубликовать проект dotnet react через Visual Studio/через терминал, но выпадает ошибка:

```
fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents
node install
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
  node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.2 and node@11.7.0 (node-v67 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
  node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v67-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
  node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.2 and node@11.7.0 (node-v67 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  In file included from In file included from ../fsevents.cc:../fsevents.cc85:
  :../src/methods.cc:8514:
  :../src/methods.cc:1412::12 :warning : warning: 'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]'Call' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    handler->Call(3, argv);
              ^  handler->Call(3, argv);

              ^
  ../../nan/nan.h:1673:3: ../../nan/nan.hnote:: 1673'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here:
  3: note: 'Call' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
    ^
    NAN_DEPRECATED inline v8::Local<v8::Value>
    ^
  ../../nan/nan.h:103:40../../nan/nan.h:103:40: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
  # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                          ^
  : note: expanded from macro 'NAN_DEPRECATED'
  # define NAN_DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                          ^
  1 warning generated.
  1 warning generated.
  rm: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
    SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
  gyp ERR! build error 
EXEC : gyp ERR! stack error : `make` failed with exit code: 2 [/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/theCompany-react-block.csproj]
  Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64' (1)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
  gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
  gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64"
  gyp ERR! cwd /Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents
  gyp ERR! node -v v11.7.0
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
  gyp ERR! not ok 
  node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
EXEC : node-pre-gyp ERR! stack error : Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64' (1) [/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/theCompany-react-block.csproj]
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:13)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
  node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.0.0
  node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
  node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents
  node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.7.0
  node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
  node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
    COPY /Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/ClientApp/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node
    TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 install: `node install`
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

  audited 11312 packages in 14.515s
  found 366 vulnerabilities (317 low, 30 moderate, 18 high, 1 critical)
    run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
/Users/k_iren/theCompany-react-block/theCompany-react-block.csproj(38,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code -1.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP

dotnet publish returned: 1
```

Не совсем понимаю, чего именно от меня хотят. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с `node-pre-gyp`, бинарные файлы для которого не находит, потому что скорее всего была изменена версия `node.js`.

> ERR: Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.2 and node@11.7.0

Переустановите пакеты:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock package-lock.json
npm install
```